# How do I assign ILPIP to 2 or more instances of an Azure Cloud Service using the CSCFG file?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, ilpip

Azure Cloud Services are easy to deploy and scale.

I need ILPIPs for each instance(VM) in my Cloud Service, I believe I can get up to 5 (Reserved) ILPIPs.

The question is how to assign the ILPIPs to EACH INSTANCE. And what the impact is on the auto-scale feature.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer finally. Just add the following to your service configuration file.

```
  <NetworkConfiguration>
    <AddressAssignments>
      <InstanceAddress roleName="FsService">
        <PublicIPs>
          <PublicIP name="FsClusterIp"/>
        </PublicIPs>
      </InstanceAddress>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
```

You will need to use powershell to find out the actual Public IP address assigned. This IP may change. If you want to use a RESERVED IP, that is guaranteed not to change, that is also possible but not free.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this to be a comment on the answer below, but don't have enough points. In your question you asked how to set ILPIPs to multiple roles instances, yet your answer isn't clear if this is the full solution. Specifically, does the following seciton

```
<PublicIP name="FsClusterIp"/>
```

need to be duplicated (and assigned a unique name) for each instance of your FsService role? So for a deployment with three instances of FsService...

```
<PublicIP name="FsClusterIp1"/>
<PublicIP name="FsClusterIp2"/>
<PublicIP name="FsClusterIp3"/>
```

or is the solution simply as it is in your answer.

Did this work when deploying your service (roles) to an existing CLoud Service, or did you have to create a new Cloud Service when deploying.

Comment: Sorry if my answer was not clear. You do not need to duplicate the PublicIP node at all. You will get a new IP for each instance using my suggestion above. However, you will not know the IP addresses unless you use powershell. Finally, it works on existing cloud services. No need to re create.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

I've added the following to my cscfg

`<NetworkConfiguration>
    <AddressAssignments>
      <InstanceAddress roleName="MqttWorkerRole">
        <PublicIPs>
          <PublicIP name="MqttWorker1Ip" 
 domainNameLabel="MqttWorker1Ip"/>          
        </PublicIPs>
      </InstanceAddress>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>`

But it doesn't seem to work, I only get 1 public IP which is used for both worker role instances. I need 1 static public IP for each worker role instance so that I can load balance using DNS.